# WrapPanel Content Alignment

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, wrappanel, alignment

I have a `toolkit:WrapPanel` showing in my WP7 app, I have 5 items and the first row only has enough space for 3 items, I would like the wrap panel to place 3 items on the first row, followed by the 2 on the second row being centered.

At the moment it looks like this

```
* * *
* *
```

but I want the panel to do this

```
* * *
 * *
```

Do I have to implement my own panel or are there changes to the toolkit WrapPanel i can make?

Can there even be an option of how many item I would like on a particular row?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the standard WrapPanel but size the container to allow space for 5 items and insert a blank placeholder (of the same width as the actual content) after each real element you add.

This will create the offsetting you're after much like the spaces prepresent a placeholder and the asterisks represent actual content in your example.

Comment: sounds like an ugly hack ... but ... the phone has a screen fixed width / height, so this approach isn't that bad.